# How to use ndk-stack with tombstone file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, urhosharp

I am developing Android app using Xamarin and UrhoSharp. My app crashes when i close the Activity containing UrhoSharp surface giving SIGSEGV as:

```
[Mono] Searching for 'RefCounted_ReleaseRef'.
[Mono] Probing 'RefCounted_ReleaseRef'.
[Mono] Found as 'RefCounted_ReleaseRef'.
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_object_new_fast (intptr) <IL 0x00025, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure) <IL 0x00000, 0x00023>
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] Attempting native Android stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at mono_object_new_fast+0 [0x5e446dd4]
[mono-rt]   at ???+15172 [0x5ab12b44]
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x71d30000 (code=1), thread 17476 (SDLThread)
```

Somebody suggested to use tombstone file and ndk-stack to get detailed error message. But I am confused on what to provide for the "-sym" part of ndk-stack.

What does "full path to the root directory for symbols" mean in ndk-stack?

I am using UrhoSharp version 1.1.121 and Xamarin Version 4.0.3.214.

Comment: Does any solution available for this issue?